# Is it possible to call a function from static library that built in Rust using C?

Tags: c, rust

A function from Rust that built as static library called in C

```
// Rust
fn message() -> String

// C
int main() {
    message()
}
```

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-01-unsafe-rust.html#using-extern-functions-to-call-external-code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Setting up a project

Create a new `cargo` library as usual:

```sh
$ cargo new my_rust_library --lib
```

You can then configure `cargo` to emit a systems library instead of its regular rust target:

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib"]      # dynamic lib
# crate-type = ["staticlib"] # static lib
```

### Building a C API

You can mark a function as `extern "C"` to tell the compiler to use the C ABI. You also need to add the `#[no_mangle]` annotation to tell the compiler not to mangle the name of this function:

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn message() {
  println!("Hello C!")
}
```

### Linking

You can build your crate as usual:

```sh
$ cargo build --release
```

`cargo` will create a `my_lib.so` or `my_lib.a` file in the `target/release` directory. This library can simply be linked by your build system. However, calling a Rust function from C requires a header file to declare the function signatures.

Every `extern fn` needs to have a corresponding header function.

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn message() {}
```

would become:

```c
void message(void);
```

You can automate this process with [`cbindgen`](https://github.com/eqrion/cbindgen), a crate which analyzes your Rust code and generates the corresponding C/C++ headers. You can install it with `cargo`:

```sh
$ cargo install cbindgen
```

Create an empty config file:

```sh
$ touch cbindgen.toml
```

And generate the header file:

```sh
$ cbindgen --config cbindgen.toml --crate my_rust_library --output my_header.h --lang c
```

Now you can simply include the header and call you Rust functions from C!

```c
#include "my_header.h"
message()
```

Comment: Could you add to your answer the command line code for building rust shared library? Thanks

Comment: @yoell32 Sure, I updated my answer